# Bayesian two independent sample test. Error missing value TRUE/FALSE and NaNs produced

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian

I am trying to run a Bayesian test to compare two samples following this [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/135725/194218). However, I get this error:

```
Error in if (runif(1) < ratio) parameters <- candidate : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

It seems that since the sample has calculations using 0, I am getting NaNs. 
Any suggestion to solve this and proceed with the test?

```
sample.2 <- c(1.3,1.3,1.9,1.4,1.4,1.7,1.9)
sample.1 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1.5,1.5,2,2,2,2,2,2)

mean(sample.2)
#we need a pooled data set for estimating parameters in the prior.
pooled <- c(sample.1, sample.2)
par(mfrow=c(1, 2))

hist(sample.1)
hist(sample.2)

likelihood <- function(parameters){
  mu1=parameters[1]; sig1=parameters[2]; mu2=parameters[3]; sig2=parameters[4]
  prod(dnorm(sample.1, mu1, sig1)) * prod(dnorm(sample.2, mu2, sig2))
}

prior <- function(parameters){
  mu1=parameters[1]; sig1=parameters[2]; mu2=parameters[3]; sig2=parameters[4]
  dnorm(mu1, mean(pooled), 1000*sd(pooled)) * dnorm(mu2, mean(pooled), 1000*sd(pooled)) * dexp(sig1, rate=0.1) * dexp(sig2, 0.1)
}

posterior <- function(parameters) {likelihood(parameters) * prior(parameters)}

#starting values
mu1 = 1.3; sig1 = 0.8; mu2 = 1.3; sig2 = 0.8
parameters <- c(mu1, sig1, mu2, sig2)

#this is the MCMC /w Metropolis method
n.iter <- 10000
results <- matrix(0, nrow=n.iter, ncol=4)
results[1, ] <- parameters
for (iteration in 2:n.iter){
  candidate <- parameters + rnorm(4, sd=0.5)
  ratio <- posterior(candidate)/posterior(parameters)
  if (runif(1) < ratio) parameters <- candidate #Metropolis modification
  results[iteration, ] <- parameters
}

#burn-in
results <- results[500:n.iter,]

mu1 <- results[,1]
mu2 <- results[,3]

hist(mu1 - mu2)
```

Comment: You end up with negative values for the standard deviation in `candidate`, you'll need to figure out a way of generating candidates that doesn't produce negative SDs.

Comment: I add 10 to all values, I obtain positive values for the standard deviations and it is still happening? posterior(candidate) remains being 0. Any suggestion of how I should initialize this?